# XPS L501x fedora 16 headphones not muting speakers

Tags: fedora

Untill the last updates whenever I plugged in my headphones the speakers were muted but now it seems I can't mute them anymore. Any Ideeas about I could resolv this?

Thanks,
Virgil

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command:

**alsamixer -c0**

And enable the Auto-Mute option.

Comment: thanks, but I can;t test it as I switched to ubuntu when fedora crashed after some updates a while ago.